# How to make EditText regain focus?

Tags: android, android-activity, setfocus, android-edittext, clickable

I have one activity with an EditText and a button. When the button is pressed, I call

```
myEditText.setClickable(false);
myEditText.setFocusable(false);
```

I have another button, which when pressed, changes the activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DestinationScreen.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

When I return from activity2 to my main activity which has the EditText, I want it to regain the focus. That is, I want to be able to type in some new values in it. Any idea how that is possible?

I tried to do this in my main Activity

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
myEditText.setClickable(true);
myEditText.setFocusable(true);
myEditText.requestFocus();
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you'd like the `EditText` to regain focus when you return from the second activity.
Then probably that's what you should try: since you are already invoking the activity2 with the `startActivityForResult` method (requestCode: 0), you could take advantage of it:

You should override the

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

method inside your main activity, check whether the `requestCode == 0`, and if so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 0:
            EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
            myEditText.setClickable(true);
            myEditText.setFocusable(true);
            myEditText.requestFocus();
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @rekaszeru , I am still not able to edit the text. Whatever I had entered previously is still visible and I am not able to type in anything.

Comment: Make sure that your myEditText is initialized locally, it shouldn't be a global variable

Comment: I am able to do this in my main activity after the return from activity2
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.code);
b.setClickable(true);

I am still not able to use
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
            myEditText.setClickable(true);
            myEditText.setFocusable(true);
            myEditText.requestFocus();
to good effect.

Comment: Any help? I am still not able to get it.

Comment: Do you get any exception? Does the onActivityResult method of your main activity get called?

Comment: Nothing. I am able to make the buttons clickable again by using b.setClickalbe(true);
I am not able to do the same for EditText.
I have declared all the variables locally

Comment: However, I am able to use myEditText.setText("SomeTEXT"); Only that is working.

Comment: Yes, onActivityResult method of my main activity gets called. That is where I have added,
b.setClickalbe(true);

Comment: I'll look into it as soon as i get home.

Comment: @rekaszeru, Thanks a lot. It's working fine now. I just called myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: Please don't forget to post your solution here, and accept it (for accepting your own answer, you have to wait 2 days), so that this issue to be marked as solved, and others can learn from it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't stepped through the Android source to fact check this, but the symptoms imply to me that:

- `#onActivityResult()` is called sometime before `#onResume()`, and
- requesting focus probably requires the view to be shown, which isn't true yet (because the activity's view hierarchy isn't attached to its window, see `View#isShown()`).

As such, you can fix it by requesting focus from a runnable on the main thread, which will run immediately after the activity is resumed. In your `onActivityResult()` definition:

```
final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myEditText.requestFocus();
        // Also move the cursor to the end
        myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.length());
    }
});
```