# Android: How to regain focus of EditText when switching between Activities in ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-edittext, activitygroup

I have an *Activity A* in an ActivityGroup with an EditText widget. When switching to *Activity B* (within the same ActivityGroup) and using the back button to go back to Activity A again, i cannot bring up the software keyboard when tapping the EditText. How can I solve this? Seems to be a focus issue similar to this

[How to make EditText regain focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758645/how-to-make-edittext-regain-focus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using the approach on this post:
[call onrestart/onresume when click on back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378867/call-onrestart-onresume-when-click-on-back-button)

This way the (child) activity's onResume() method is always called when switching between actitvities and my EditText works (brings up the software keyboard) as expected!

Answer (score 0):

add this in xml file in Edittext

android:focusable="true"